# Game Development: Open source project like Crayon Physics?

Tags: open-source, physics, game-physics

[Crayon Physics](http://www.crayonphysics.com/) is a wonderful game because of the real motion of all the objects. Gravity and collision are two very important things in that game. I know that is the reason why it costs $19.95

**Are there  equivalent open source projects?** I'm very interested in the code and all the physical laws. Or do I still have to go to school for a few years and then write it my own....

[Here](http://www.spele.nl/game/stapelen/super_stacker_2.html) is another example (in Flash) where there are nice physics.
I don't know with which words I should search for a project like this.

Thanks

Comment: what exactly is the question?

Comment: I think he'd like to have the source code of crayon physics and since there is none he's looking for something similar with open source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of open source physics engines. For example, have a look at the engines listed in [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics_engine#Real-time_physics_engines).

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few open-source physics libraries depending on what language you plan on using and if you need them for 3D/2D, but the best I know of are [bullet](http://code.google.com/p/bullet/) for 3D and [Box2D](http://code.google.com/p/box2d/) for 2D

Comment: you can always shoehorn a 3D engine into a 2D space with constraints, but I don't know about if it'd be as effective than a 2D only engine.

Answer (score 2):

Martijn, I'll bite.

Numpty Physics, (released open-source, GPL, here: http://numptyphysics.garage.maemo.org/ ) is a free game similar to Crayon Physics.  It uses the Box2D physics engine (box2d.org) and has a built-in level editor.

In addition to the source code, you will also find binary packages for many popular operating systems.

Here's a shortcut to the code if you are impatient... 8)

https://garage.maemo.org/scm/?group_id=638

Hope that helps you out...
-Alan